# SharePoint 2013: Making a predetermined Due Date based on Created Date

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a task list in SharePoint 2013 that will be saved as a template, and I'd like it to have hard due dates already set in the template tasks everytime this list is created and recreated.
So it has tasks already built in, and say a new list is created, I want those tasks to have due dates that kick off a given number of days from the Created date.

E.G.:

```
  Task    |     Created     |    Due
--------------------------------------------
 Thing    |    10/1/2013    | =DATE(DAY([Created])+14)
```

I've tried multiple versions of this formula in the Calculated Column, but none work. I'd also like the Due date to be in the Date format (10/1/2013). This is not a View for filtering the list, but an actual column in the list itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So update: I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx), which goes into more detail about calculated formulas, but still no bueno in SharePoint 2013. I made a Start Date column (regular Date/Time column), a Time Gap column (regular number column), and then went to make a calculated Due Date column that would be =[Start Date]+[Time Gap] (E.G.: 12/1/13 + 10, so third column would be 12/11/13). But nothing is taking...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
I made a Date and Time column that auto-populated Today's Date, called "Milestone Start".
Then I made a Number column that only took whole numbers, called "Milestone Gap".
Then the final column, I made a Calculated column, called "Milestone Due Date", with the following formula:

```
=TEXT([Milestone Start]+[Milestone Gap],"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

The returned data type is set to "Single line of text" and works exactly as intended.